# Tower of Hanoi Python My own way wont work

Tags: python, recursion

I tried solving this problem but it did not work. Seems like the recursion does not stop.

What i wanted to do was to move ndisks from tower A to C 1 by 1 starting from the top.

```
def Move(src, dest):
     dest.append(src.pop())

def Hanoi(nDisks, src, dest, temp):
    numDiskMoved = 0

    while numDiskMoved < nDisks:                
            if len(dest) == 0:   #dest is empty, go ahead and move
                              Move(src, dest)
                              numDiskMoved += 1

            elif dest[-1] > src[-1]:  #dest disk is bigger than src Disk. Still a valid move
                                    Move(src, dest)
                                    numDiskMoved += 1

            else:  #situation where dest disk is smaller than src disk
                 newNDisks = len(dest) #move all of current dest disks to temp
                 Hanoi(newNDisks, dest, temp, src)
                 Move(src, dest)
                 numDiskMoved += 1
                 Hanoi(newNDisks, temp, dest, src)

a = [3, 2, 1]
b = []
c = []

Hanoi(len(src), a, c, b)
print(c)
```

Comment: What's the point of keeping track of the number of disks moved? AFAIK you don't need the loop at all.

Comment: IMO we can't really help inventing "your own way". We could help with the conventional solution, but that wouldn't answer your question.

Comment: Its homework to come up with alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is wrong. It does not have a clear base case (it looks like it does within the while loop but that depends on the nDisks which changes for each call).

I don't think all the intermediate moves you are making are logical. For example, moving from src to dest if it can be made, how does that help in solving it? What's the reason for not moving it to temp?

Here's the correct version:

```py
def tower_of_hanoi(n_disks, src, dest, temp):
    if n_disks == 1:
        disk = src.pop()
        dest.append(disk)
        return
    tower_of_hanoi(n_disks - 1, src, temp, dest)
    tower_of_hanoi(1, src, dest, None)
    tower_of_hanoi(n_disks - 1, temp, dest, src)
```

Comment: Yea i get it the conventional way is to tackle the problem from the bottom ring. Im just trying to tackle the problem from the top ring

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code:

```
def Move(src, dest):
     dest.append(src.pop())

def Hanoi(n, src, dest, temp):
    if n == 0:
        return
    Hanoi(n-1, src, temp, dest)
    Move(src, dest)
    print a, c, b
    Hanoi(n-1, temp, dest, src)

a = [3, 2, 1]
b = []
c = []

Hanoi(3, a, c, b)
```

Here is the output:

```
[3, 2] [1] []
[3] [1] [2]
[3] [] [2, 1]
[] [3] [2, 1]
[1] [3] [2]
[1] [3, 2] []
[] [3, 2, 1] []
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the errors!

```
#Moves the top ring from source to destination tower
def Move(src,dest):
    dest.append(src.pop())


#Moves nDisks:num of disks  from src:source to dest:destination with help
#from temp:temporary tower
def Hanoi(nDisks, src, dest, temp):

    numDisksMoved = 0

    while numDisksMoved < nDisks:

        #Case where destination is empty
        if len(dest) == 0:
            Move(src,dest)
            numDisksMoved += 1

        #Case where destination has a ring bigger than source
        elif dest[-1] > src[-1]:
            Move(src,dest)
            numDisksMoved +=1

        #Case where destination has a ring smaller than source
        else:

            MovedTillNow = numDisksMoved

            #Need to move whatever i have "MOVED Till Now":MovedTillNow from
            #destination to temporary tower
            Hanoi(MovedTillNow,dest,temp,src)

            #Move a ring from source to destination 
            Move(src,dest)
            numDisksMoved +=1

            #Need to move back previously moved rings back to original tower
            Hanoi(MovedTillNow,temp,dest,src)



#Our 3 towers

TA = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
TB = []
TC = []

Hanoi(len(TA),TA,TC,TB)

print(TC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at my solution in Python.

```
def hanoiTowers(origin, buffer, to, N = None):
    if N is None:
        N = origin.size()    
    if N > 1:
        hanoiTowers(origin, to, buffer, N-1)
    to.push(origin.pop())
    if N > 1:
        hanoiTowers(buffer, origin, to, N-1)
```

For tests and Stack class please go to:
https://github.com/GA1/Algorithms/blob/master/Various/python/